# How do I get data from Dynamics CRM online in to my SQL server using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I can't believe that I have not yet found the answer to this question.

All I want to know is where to start in terms of using SQL tools (queries or SSIS I assume) to query CRM online (2013) and bring data into a table.

Is this even possible?

I want to download data, then I want to transform then I want to put it back. I'm sure I can work out that once I know to start!!!

Many thanks, Warren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, CRM Online doesn't give you *direct* access to the database layer via SSMS.

There are some good samples in the [CRM SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=207027) that show how to retrieve data if you are up for writing some C#.  This is their intro sample for how to connect to your CRM instance, gather some data, display it, and then update the entities. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675400.aspx

Once you manage to connect to your CRM instance, you will have access to all of your CRM data objects.

Answer (score 2):

What I can suggest you based on my experience is you can get Data From CRM Online to your SQL using SSIS and you can use [SSIS Integration Toolkit for CRM](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm) for it.

Comment: I vouch for this. Free for BIDS use only. We're using the normal licence and it works well in both directions. I get what I need into a local table on a regular timed basis and then query to my heart's content in SSMS.